# SQL Server: assign value for character and get average value for each user

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say there is a field in the table called `class_nr` and sample values of `class_nr` are E,U,R,O,P,S.

```
+---------+-------------+
| user_id | class_nr    |
+---------+-------------+
| 1       | E           |
| 1       | O           |
| 1       | E           |
| 2       | P           |
| 2       | R           |
| 2       | U           |
+---------+-------------+
```

Points for class:

```
E=5
U=4
R=3
O=2
P=1
```

Now I want to calculate average points for a user for the `class_nr` he has. For example `user_id` 1 has 2 `E`s and 1 `O`. So he has average points:

```
(5+2+5)/3 = 4
```

Similarly `user_id`2 gets:

```
(1+3+4)/3 = 2.67
```

How can I achieve this with single SQL query in SQL Server?

Comment: I'd create a help table Points_for_class,  join with it, do group by with AVG etc. (Or a CASE if no extra table.)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have opportunity to create or modify tables in the DB. I can just retrieve data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use a `CASE` expression to give each class_nr it's correct numeric value:

```
select user_id, SUM(case class_nr when 'E' then 5.0
                                  when 'U' then 4.0
                                  when 'R' then 3.0
                                  when 'O' then 2.0
                                  when 'P' then 1.0 end) / count(*)
from tablename
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use average function directly instead of doing sum and count:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    user_id INT
    ,class_nr CHAR(1)
    )

    INSERT INTO #temp
    VALUES (
    1
    ,'E'
    )
    ,(
    1
    ,'O'
    )
    ,(
    1
    ,'E'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'P'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'R'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'U'
    )



    select user_id,avg(case when class_nr = 'E' then 5.0
    when class_nr = 'O' then 2.0
    when class_nr = 'P' then 1.0
    when class_nr = 'R' then 3.0
    when class_nr = 'u' then 4.0

     end) from #temp group by user_id
```